Why is swapping using function and swapping using assignment produce in different results?
This is the code for Quick sort in which i used assignment to swap the values.
def partion(arr,low,high):
  partion_index=low
  pivot=arr[partion_index]

  while (low < high):
    while low < len(arr) and (arr[low]<=pivot):
      low+=1
    while (arr[high]>=pivot):
      high-=1
    if (low < high):
      arr[low],arr[high]=arr[high],arr[low]

  pivot,arr[high]=arr[high],pivot
  return high   

def quickSort(arr,low,high):
  if(low <high):
    p=partion(arr,low,high)
    quickSort(arr,low,p-1)
    quickSort(arr,p+1,high)

This is producing the wrong results. When i tried using swap function for the same job it worked.
def swap(a, b, arr):
    if a!=b:
        tmp = arr[a]
        arr[a] = arr[b]
        arr[b] = tmp

def partion(arr,low,high):
  partion_index=low
  pivot=arr[partion_index]

  while (low < high):
    while low < len(arr) and (arr[low]<=pivot):
      low+=1
    while (arr[high]>=pivot):
      high-=1
    if (low < high):
      swap(low, high, arr)
      
  swap(partion_index, high, arr)
  return high

Why is it so?

The second-to-last lines pivot,arr[high]=arr[high],pivot and swap(partion_index, high, arr) in each version of partition() do not appear to be equivalent.

Maybe try arr[partition_index],arr[high]=arr[high],pivot instead of pivot,arr[high]=arr[high],pivot?

Welcome to SO! Please read [mre] - there's a lot of code here; it's expected that you reduce it to the bare minimum before asking a question here.

(There is a Style Guide for Python Code.)

When swapping the pivot, you are swapping with the pivot variable and not the array[partion_index]. Changing it to the below should make it equivalent to the swap approach.
array[partion_index], arr[high] = arr[high], array[partion_index]

Note: I didn't really check the overall validity of the QuickSort implementation though.
